# Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

I have the following code that brings in 3 posts or project posts;

But I'd like it to show only posts form the current post category;

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<article class="post">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content-portfolio' );


rainy_projectbottom_nav();
endwhile;
?>
</div>
</article>
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="header">
<h2 class="subtitle">Check out more projects</h2>
</header>
<div class="grid"><?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

endwhile;

$cats = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rainy_multicheck', false );

$terms_args = array(
'exclude' => $cats
);

$terms = get_terms( 'project-category', $terms_args );

$query_args = array(
'post_type' => 'project',
'project-category' => 'Print',
'tax_query' => array(
 array(
    'taxonomy' => 'project-category',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => $cats,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
   )
  ),
  'posts_per_page' => 3
  );

   $portfolio_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

  if ( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : $portfolio_query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content-related' );
 endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();

  else :
  get_template_part( 'content-none' );
 endif;
  ?></div> </div></main> <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: To be clear, you want to edit *the main search page* and bring in posts from the category the search originated in? So you have a search form on your category page and if someone searches from a category, you want to pass that to your search page and pull results based on that category?

Comment: no this is just bring in 'related projects' on a post page;

Comment: Can you edit your question ( by clicking the `edit` button above ) to clarify your question a bit. Maybe add the code where the variable `$cats` is set.

Comment: So you want to make a "related projects" that shows only posts from the same Custom Post Type (portfolio in your case). Is it right?

Comment: Yes thats right; I have it working if I set it manually; have updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_get_post_terms()` to pull the terms.

```
$taxonomy = 'project-category';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy); 
var_dump($terms);
```

`wp_get_post_terms()` will return an array of terms because multiple terms may be assigned to a single post. This means that you will potentially get a set of terms, not just one, so you will need to choose which to use. That is, the first terms? The last term? The first would be `$terms[0]->slug` for example. This would be the case for your "pattern" here:

```
'post_type' => 'project',
'project-category' => 'Print',
```

[You can alternately use a `tax_query` as found in the Codex:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

```
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'project-category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
    ),
```

Which in your case would look like:

```
$taxonomy = 'project-category';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy,array("fields" => "ids")); 

  $query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'project-category',
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => $terms,
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 2
);
```

Comment: So what if I wanted to get the posts  'project-category' and display posts with that 'project-cateogry'

Comment: That is what this code does. It pulls the term from the  "project-category" taxonomy that is assigned to the post. You already have the rest of query set up. Can't you plug that small piece in?

Comment: @DarrenPennell : see the edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit - but think Im confusing matters possibly; as far as I can see this would bring in posts with the project-category of actors? I don't want to have to have to add in 'actor' manually, does that make sense? apologies if not

Comment: Sorry. The "actor" part should have been changed when I copied this over. That line is the "taxonomy". The terms ***for the post*** are pulled in via the `$terms` variable set above the query.

Comment: Ive updated the code I have in the template, would the above code still be relevant? minus the 'project-category' => 'Print',

Comment: This is great @ s_ha_dum thank you for your patience! :-)
Could I exclude the current post from the search too?